# Is it possible to use static terms inside Formie email notification?

Tags: craft4, plugin-formie

This is my first time using formie and it looks really nice. Thank you for the plugin.
I just have an issue with translations in notification. So here is some context :

I have a form with static terms in `formie.php` for labels (that's working in front-end), and I'd like to get the translated labels inside the email notification too.

I tried these inside *formie > forms > email notifications > **email content***

```
First name

{{"First name"|t}}

{{"First name"|t([],"fr")}}

{"First name"|t}
```

But none of these are working...

Is it possible to have static terms in emails ? If not, what would be the workaround?

Thank you !

**Here is my config :**

- Craft CMS : 4.4.1
- Verbb/Formie : 2.0.24

---

[EDIT]

Okay, I don't have the solution for static translation inside Email Content field for the notification. But I found "custom email template", so I guess I'm gonna go for that solution.
[Doc](https://verbb.io/craft-plugins/formie/docs/template-guides/email-templates)

---

[EDIT 2]

`{{"First name"|t("formie")}}` did the trick. The email notification uses `site.php` file by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, finally I solved the mystery.
Static terms work well in the Email Content field.

The problem was that my template uses the `formie.php` file for translations. While formie email notification use `site.php`.

So somehting like `{{"First name"|t("formie")}}` did the trick.